# Windows Mobile 6 Capture Image after specified interval

Tags: windows-mobile-6

I need to capture image from Windows Mobile PDA after specified interval..

Kindly tell me any code... I tried so many forums but didn't found any working solution:s

Answer (score 1):

It's not a tested solution, but I believe this should do the trick.

In your main program

- Create a timer thread.
- Launch a camera capture dialog.
- Use the FindWindow to find the window handle to the camera capture dialog.
- Fake the needed keypress to save the image with PostKeybdMessage(typical will be left soft menu to take picture, then left soft menu to dismiss camera dialog).
- Retrieve filename from the camera capture dialog.

I'll advice you to use Windows Mobile Professional to avoid problems with security.